# How to uninstall "not installed" apps

Tags: applications, uninstallation

I just found out that some apps that I uninstall from my tablet are still listed in "all apps" section by my device, although marked as "not installed":

[image: Apps list]
<sup>Apps List (click image for larger variant)</sup>

How can I fully remove them? Please note that those are not system apps or pre-installed apps by manufacturer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you have multiple users on your tablet, this means that the apps are installed by another user, and therefore take up space without being installed under your user account. Just open the other accounts and uninstall the apps from there.

Answer (score 21):

Settings -> Apps -> select your app
tap on menu button (3 dots) -> Uninstall for all users

Comment: Perfect answer...

Comment: It should be the right one. Save my day

Answer (score 7):

In the menu there is an option to uninstall for all users so you don't have to loging in to each user on the main.